# insert into select max+1 in mysql

Tags: mysql, max

It has two tables.
Using the data from table B, we try to insert to table A.
However, the results I intended do

A

```
mid itemcode seq
1 101 1
1 101 2
1 102 3
2 101 1
2 102 2
```

B

```
mid itemcode seq
1 101 1
1 102 1
2 101 1
2 102 1
3 101 1
```

the result that I want.

```
mid itemcode seq
1 101 1
1 101 2
1 102 3
1 101 4
1 102 5
2 101 1
2 102 2
2 102 3
2 102 4
3 101 1
```

query

```
insert into A (memberid,itemcode,seq)
select B.memberid, B.itemcode, max(A.seq)+1 from A A ,B B where A.memberid=B.memberid group by B.memberid, B.itemcode;
```

and wrong result.

```
mid itemcode seq
1 101 1
1 101 2
1 102 3
1 101 4
1 102 4
2 101 1
2 102 2
2 102 3
2 102 3
3 101 1
```

Is there any good way?

Comment: Use BEFORE INSERT trigger for this operation. Of course avoid parallel inserts (lock the table), and remove the trigger immediately after the operation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the row_number() function, it might help you

```
insert into tab_a (mid,itemcode,seq)
select B.mid, 
       B.itemcode, 
       ifnull(max(A.seq), 0) + row_number() over(partition by mid)
  from tab_a A
  right join tab_b B 
    on A.mid = B.mid 
 group by B.mid, B.itemcode;
```

see [db_fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2AkmMTd4JTc51Xs1yPjeJa/0)